# Android - Is that OK to use two words as package name?

Tags: java, android, javapackager

I am building an Android App. Is that OK to use two words as package name?

For example:

```
com.myapp
com.puzzlegame
com.dingdong
```

What is the reason behind using three words as a package name?

For example:

```
com.myapp.android
com.puzzlegame.something
com.dingdong.pingpong
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: To create unique namespaces; nothing more.

Comment: YES, you can for sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the two names as well:

> And although the application ID looks like a traditional Java package
>   name, the naming rules for the application ID are a bit more
>   restrictive:
>
> ```
> It must have at least two segments (one or more dots).
> Each segment must start with a letter.
> All characters must be alphanumeric or an underscore [a-zA-Z0-9_].
> ```

Check the official doc for more info:

For more information please visit this link: [Set the application ID](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id)

Comment: Do accept the answer if was helpful so that others may know the correct answer. If any doubt pls do ask!

Answer (score 1):

The package name is traditionally a reverse domain name with the application name as an added segment. When you create a sample android project, the package name is usually **com.example.app**. This is assuming that your domain name is **example.com** and your application name is app so the reverse will end up being **com.example.app**